# Does QProcess::startDetached emit a signal when it finishes?

Tags: c++, qt, signals, qprocess

I'm trying to start a process, but I need to be able to get an event when the process has terminated.

Do I get a `finished` signal if I start a `QProcess` using [`startDetached()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qprocess.html#startDetached)?

Answer (score 6):

No you can't get a signal when you use startDetached because you have no object.

startDetached is a static function and when you call it the process is started directly without creating a QProcess object. Therefore, even if there was a signal you would not be able to connect it to anything since you have no object to connect from.

If you want a signal you should create a QProcess object and then call start on it. You will then be able to get the finished signal when the process finishes.