# PyQT 4 fnished() signal would not emit

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

```
class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    self.process = QtCore.QProcess(self)
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.process,QtCore.SIGNAL("finished(int)"),self.processCompleted)

    def processCompleted(self):
        self.ui.statusText.setText("Finished")
    self.process.startDetached(command,arguments)
```

I am not able to get the finished signal emitted here. Can anybody help me here.

Comment: I have just discovered that above statement works fine with process.start. Any idea what to for startDetached()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`startDetached()` is a static method, so it's not called on an object. Therefore, no object will ever end up emitting the `finished` signal either.

As explained here: [Similar question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298060/do-i-get-a-finished-slot-if-a-start-qprocess-using-startdetached)